# How to make changes on sharepoint intranet?

Tags: sharepoint, intranet, documents, paragraphs

I will begin working on a sharepoint site, and I have to change the way this site manages the documents (Word format). The purpose is to manage the documents in paragraphs, so that you can have the right document made of the paragraphes that match with your search.

The problem is that I know nothing about sharepoint. Do you have any idea about how I can do it? With which programming langage? 
I heard that jQuery helps managing sharepoint web sites, do you think it's a good idea?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery is a client side programming library and won't be able to help you to manage documents on your server. To manage documents on your server, you will have to use the .NET framework using C# or VB.NET.